# CAS 6.6.8 - Connect OIDC application

Tags: windows, jenkins, tomcat, openid-connect, cas

I'm pretty new to CAS (6.6.8) and I'm trying to connect an test application to my CAS server using OIDC. I'm used to Okta, Auth0, etc so OIDC is not new to me, just CAS configuration.

My Cas is also connected to an AD to sign in.

This is my Cas server configuration using OIDC module (`org.apereo.cas:cas-server-support-oidc`) :

```
# Server
server.port=443

# SSL
server.ssl.enabled=true
server.ssl.key-store=file:{path}
server.ssl.key-store-password=xxx
server.ssl.key-password=xxx

# CAS
cas.server.name=https://URL:443
cas.server.prefix=${cas.server.name}/cas
cas.logout.followServiceRedirects=true
cas.authn.accept.enabled=false

# Active Directory
cas.authn.ldap[0].type=AUTHENTICATED
cas.authn.ldap[0].ldapUrl=ldap://localhost:389
cas.authn.ldap[0].useStartTls=false
cas.authn.ldap[0].baseDn=DC=AAA,DC=BBB
cas.authn.ldap[0].search-filter=(sAMAccountName={user})
cas.authn.ldap[0].subtreeSearch=true
cas.authn.ldap[0].bindDn=USER
cas.authn.ldap[0].bindCredential=XXX

# OIDC settings
cas.authn.oidc.core.issuer=https://URL/cas/oidc
cas.authn.oidc.core.skew=5
cas.authn.oidc.jwks.file-system.jwks-file=file:C:\Program Files\Tomcat 9.0\etc\cas\config\keystore.jwks

# Encryption/Signing keys
cas.tgc.crypto.encryption.key=SN7Vpa8oHvXfh2hDZp8ANxZGRkF1DvKbYLTy_Vip2dI
cas.tgc.crypto.signing.key=KwbtZl2y5sidXFMShjVm4PiGwjVQ0Fq-ZBp0A_HUK6IOnoS2h0E5cSfp7vy8uioqX04yKIBXcU0kUm6DRuPCZQ
cas.webflow.crypto.signing.key=MltIqyj_vGFgZKFfw8vmoqYIYYu_KEU20AyZaAIDZl_Xjhl0ZGpPNe4h4N7-8p1_pNi-s97TQKb1-INp9VEwEA
cas.webflow.crypto.encryption.key=3Mh_pdDFLPCMgacDL6z8SQ
```

---

This is my `/etc/config/services` file :

```
{
  "@class": "org.apereo.cas.services.OidcRegisteredService",
  "serviceId": "https://localhost:3000/callback", --> my app URL
  "name": "OIDC",
  "id": 1,
  "clientId": "41ff9715-bd3e-473c-9888-e2d5a1364c2a",
  "clientSecret": "SECRET",
  "bypassApprovalPrompt": true,
  "generateRefreshToken": true,
  "evaluationOrder": 10000
}
```

---

This is my test application config (Node.js app) :

```
{
  "domain": "URL/cas/oidc",
  "clientId": "41ff9715-bd3e-473c-9888-e2d5a1364c2a",
}
```

This application was used for other IdP so it won't come from this. When hitting login on it, this is the `/authorize` URL I'm getting redirected to :

```
https://URL/cas/oidc/authorize?client_id=41ff9715-bd3e-473c-9888-e2d5a1364c2a&acr=http%3A%2F%2Fschemas.openid.net%2Fpape%2Fpolicies%2F2007%2F06%2Fmulti-factor&scope=openid%20profile%20email%20read%3Aall&response_type=code&response_mode=query&state=dGEwS21Ddm52WUNXc254c2ptRmNzQjBOZGNTSGlPZzZ1R1AxVldOTl9lMA%3D%3D&nonce=RUIzY1hEbWJmWDZJYjNWOWh3QVJZcjBBdVNDOGt0RVdjYVl6WEZ1R0tXYQ%3D%3D&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000&code_challenge=2Mln96FLN8s0qylEMY9yuC7ucbKioF9cGMIYG5B4q8s&code_challenge_method=S256&auth0Client=eyJuYW1lIjoiYXV0aDAtc3BhLWpzIiwidmVyc2lvbiI6IjEuMTkuNCJ9
```

I didn't hide all settings as it's for a test environment.

The issue is that I'm getting redirected to a CAS page, but saying "Authorization Denied". I'm not getting redirected to the authentication page or anything like that :
[image]

I'm not finding anything on the net for this.

Answer (score 1):

You are not going to find anything about this issue on the net. Everything you need to diagnose this issue is in your cas server logs. CAS server logs are the best resource for determining the root cause of the problem, provided you have configured the appropriate log levels. Specifically you want to make sure DEBUG levels are turned on the org.apereo package in the log4j configuration.

If your server container of choice is Apache Tomcat, you may also want to look into your catalina.out and localhost-X-Y-Z.log log files to learn more about source of issues.